# Android - setOnClickListern in nav_header_menu

Tags: android, layout, menu, hamburger-menu

I would add event in nav_header_menu.

I added login and register section then when user click I would show the relative layout page:
https://ibb.co/wwmFzSk

I added fragment_layout_user.xml and ActivityLoginUser class with code:

```
public class ActivityLoginUser extends AppCompatActivity{

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.fragment_login_user);

    ActionBar ab = getSupportActionBar();
    ab.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
}}
```

How can I implement this event in drawer menu?

Comment: I tried to add it also from mobile_navigation from navigation folder declaring the fragment in Main Activity but when I try to click on "Login" from drawer menu, nothing happen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it also with @SumitSingh suggestion. I paste here the correct way to solve that.

We need to add this code in the activity class where we added navigation view.

```
    NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
View headerview = navigationView.getHeaderView(0);
TextView login= (TextView) headerview.findViewById(R.id.login);
login.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
       // Your code here 
    }
});
```

Replace // Your code here with:

```
Intent loginUserIntent = new Intent(getContext(), ActivityLoginUser.class);

            /* Start the new activity */
            startActivity(loginUserIntent);
```

If you get error for getContext() please replace it with MainActivity.this

It works for me.

Answer (score 1):

You can follow below code to access the view of header.

```
NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
View headerview = navigationView.getHeaderView(0);
TextView login= (TextView) headerview.findViewById(R.id.login);
login.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
       // Your code here 
    }
});
```

Comment: @MrPlunk Yes you need to add this code in your activity class where you added navigation view.

Comment: below // your code here, I added: `code`Intent loginUserIntent = new Intent(getContext(), ActivityLoginUser.class);

                /* Start the new activity */
                startActivity(loginUserIntent);
But it does not works and I get error on getContext()